# Is a shader program belongs to a specific material and conversely?

Tags: opengl, 3d

I'm coding a 3D engine and I wonder if a shader program always belongs to a specific material. In other words, can I load a specific shader program instance (with a specific behaviour) from a specific material?

For example imagine we have in our scene 3 objects (a cube, a sphere and a cylinder) each one of them rendered with a different shading :

- The cube with a simple 'color' shading
- The sphere with a 'texture color' shading
- The cylinder rendered with a 'ADS texture color' (ambient, diffuse, specular) shading (light)

So here we can associate to these cases 3 differents materials :

For the cube :

```
color : rgb glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) or rgba glm::vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
```

For the sphere :

```
color : rgb glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) or rgba glm::vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
texture : color_map (map_Kd for example) sphere_texture.bmp
```

For the cylinder :

```
color : rgb glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) or rgba glm::vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
texture : color_map (map_Kd for example) sphere_texture.bmp
light :
         - Ka glm::vec3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f) (ambient)
         - Kd glm::vec3 (0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f) (diffuse)
         - Ks glm::vec3(0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f) (specular)
```

So here in these cases if I load a mesh with a specific material the corresponding shader program will be loaded ? Is it true in all cases ?

What do you think about this ?

Comment: Why is unity3d tag listed here?

Comment: Also, the question is quite unclear. What materials are you talking about. About fixed-function materials? Then it has nothing to do with shaders. If you are talking about materials of your engine... Well, dude, it's strange that you ask such a question here.

Comment: A material represents all the data (color, texture, light components) which define the wrapping of the object (meshes) and the manner in which it responds to the light (ambient, diffuse, specular and shininess components). These informations have to be send to the shader program. So a shader program NEEDS a material. So there is a interaction between them.

Comment: You can use multiple textures/parameters with the same shader. If you standardize your uniform names, vertex attributes, and texture units, you can also use multiple shaders with the same material (though I'm not sure what the use of that would be). What you want to do in your engine is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

No, a shader program does not "belong" to a material, rather a material are the parameters passed to the shader program describing the surface properties of polygons and how to light them.

It is very common to use the same shader program to render several object that share identical or similar materials. A popular approach with developer is the use of *uber shaders*, which are big parameterized programs that can handle several types of materials.